# My EditItemTemplate isn't loading in my gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got this gridview:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="gv_cats" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    cellpadding="10" 
    CssClass="std_tbl" 
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
    Height="98px" 
    OnRowDataBound="gv_cats_RowDataBound" 
    OnRowDeleting="gv_cats_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CustOrder" SortExpression="CustOrder">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustOrder") %>'/>                        
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="editCustOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustOrder") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SalesOrder" SortExpression="SalesOrder">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SalesOrder") %>'/>                        
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="editSalesOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SalesOrder") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The code runs fine and loading as well. But when trying to press the ItemTemplate field nothing happens. I want to be able to load my EditItemTemplate and edit the cell. What am I missing?

Comment: The EditItemTemplate is shown when the GridView switches into edit mode. That happens when an edit button is clicked. I see you `AutoGenerateDeleteButton` but you don't `AutoGenerateEditButton` or manually declare an edit button. [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.edititemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EditItemTemplate is shown when the GridView switches into edit mode. That happens when an edit button is clicked. There are a few ways to do this.

On the GridView, set `AutoGenerateEditButton` to true.

```
AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
```

Or create a command field that shows the edit button.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    ....
</Columns>
```

Or within the GridView, create a button that has `CommandName` set to "Edit".

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
       Text="Text"
       CommandName="Edit" />
```